# Flux of a vector field through the boundary of a closed surface

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-fields, surface-integrals

I am supposed to calculate the flux of the vector field $G(r) = x \hat e_x + y \hat e_y + z \hat e_z$ through the boundary of the volume $V$ defined by $ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1, z\geq 0$ (the northern hemisphere of the sphere of radius 1 centred at the origin. The formula would be $$\iint \vec G(r) \cdot d\vec S $$for a sphere, the vectorial surface area element is: $R^2 \sin \theta d\theta d \phi$. I don't understand how I can compute this, as $d \vec S$ is given in spherical polar coordinates but $\vec G(r)$ is given in cartesian coordinates. I am also given the following hint: 'first answer the question why the disc $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 $ does not contribute, then compute the flux through the curved part of the sphere. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:** the flux of $\mathbf G$ over the unit disk $\mathscr D = \{(x, y, z) \,|\, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \text{ and } z = 0\}$ is zero.

*Proof.* Using the usual polar coordinates $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta,$ we parametrize the unit disk $\mathscr D$ by $D(r, \theta) = \langle r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, 0 \rangle$ over the domain $U = \{(r, \theta) \,|\, 0 \leq r \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}.$ We have therefore that $D_r(r, \theta) = \langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0 \rangle$ and $D_\theta(r, \theta) = \langle -r \sin \theta, r \cos \theta, 0 \rangle,$ from which it follows that $(D_r \times D_\theta)(r, \theta) = \langle 0, 0, r \rangle.$ We conclude that $\mathbf G(D(r, \theta)) \cdot (D_r \times D_\theta)(r, \theta) = \langle r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta, 0 \rangle \cdot \langle 0, 0, r \rangle = 0$ so that $\iint_{\mathscr D} \mathbf G \cdot d \mathbf S = \iint_U \mathbf G(D(r, \theta)) \cdot (D_r \times D_\theta)(r, \theta) \, dr \, d \theta = 0.$ QED.

Considering that flux is additive, the flux you seek is equal to the sum of the flux on the unit disk $\mathscr D$ and the flux on the top of the northern hemisphere, i.e., the flux on $\mathscr S = \{(x, y, z) \,|\, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \text{ and } z \geq 0 \}.$ Can you compute this flux and finish the problem? (**Hint:** use spherical coordinates to parametrize $\mathscr S.$)

Comment: Thanks Carlo, this really helps. To compute the flux, I can parametrise $\delta$ by: $R^2 \sin \theta d \theta d \phi \hat e_r$, but this poses a problem, as the vector field is given in cartesian coordinates, and I don't know how to compute $\vec G(r) \cdot R^2 \sin \theta d \theta d \phi \hat e_r$

Comment: Use spherical coordinates to show that $\mathscr S$ is the image of $S(\phi, \theta) = \langle \sin \phi \cos \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \phi \rangle$ over the domain $U = \{(\phi, \theta) \,|\, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi / 2 \text{ and } 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \}.$ Like you mentioned, the normal vector to the parametrization in spherical coordinates is always $(S_\phi \times S_\theta)(\phi, \theta) = R \sin \phi S(\phi, \theta),$ but in this case $R = 1,$ so we obtain $(S_\phi \times S_\theta)(\phi, \theta) = \sin \phi S(\phi, \theta).$

Comment: We have also that $\mathbf G(S(\phi, \theta)) = S(\phi, \theta)$ so that $$\iint_\mathscr S \mathbf G \cdot d \mathbf S = \iint_U \mathbf G(S(\phi, \theta)) \cdot (S_\phi \times S_\theta)(\phi, \theta) \, d \phi \, d \theta = \iint_U \sin \phi ||S(\phi, \theta)||^2 \, d \phi \, d \theta.$$ Can you finish the integral?

Comment: Hi Carlo. Thank you so much. I can finish this integral but I'm not sure what $S(\phi, \theta)$ is

Comment: Look at my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to compute the integral and got the result $2 \pi$

Comment: Perfect. If you find that my solution solved your problem, it would be much appreciated if you could upvote and hit the check mark.